# How to update bound class in a collection on event

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a controller that is created by the Ember.Router, and this populates a table.

The template:

```
{{#each key in controller}}

  {{#view App.TestView contentBinding="key"}}

  <tr {{bindAttr class="view.isSelected"}} {{action selectKey this on="click" target="view" }}>
    <td>{{key.id}}</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" {{action removeKey on="click" target="view"}}>Remove</button></td>
  </tr>

  {{/view}}

{{/each}}
```

The code behind:

```
App.TestView = Em.View.extend({
  removeKey: function () {
    var key = this.get('content');
    this.bindingContext.removeObject(key);
    return false;
  },
  selectKey: function (event) {
    this.set('theClass', 'warning');
  },
  theClass: 'selectable',
  isSelected: function () {
    return this.get('theClass');
  }.property('theClass')
});
```

I'm expecting the onclick event to change the class to 'warning', and for the row in the collection to be highlighted in yellow (as per a css class), however this does not happen. The **isSelected** property doesn't seem to update the DOM, and I can't see why it doesn't do that.

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EsF4R/114/

Comment: Ok, [here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/EsF4R/114/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is clash between Metamorph and the table structure. Giving the tag `<tr>` to the view and putting the class binding on the `<td>` element seems to make it work, even if I think the resulting html is still weird (in particular the `<script x-start>` and `<script x-end>`)

see your modified fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/EsF4R/126/

**EDIT**

Here is a fiddle with good-looking matching tags. http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/EsF4R/129/
Moreover it sticks more to the behavior you want, ie handling class binding and click on the `tr` element instead of the `td`

Comment: Ahh thank you very much. By weird do you mean not very aesthetic but still functional? Or is there something else on your mind?

Comment: If you look at the Dom, `<script id="metamorph-0-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <tbody><tr>
       <td ><script id="metamorph-6-start" ></script>1<script id="metamorph-6-end"></script></td>
    </tr>
    <script id="metamorph-0-end"></script>....</tbody>`

I would prefer that the metamorph-0-end will arrive after the closing tbody.